# ValueError: Unknown config_item:L1L2 for load_model_hdf5 function from Keras package in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and have installed keras with tensorflow gpu 2.2. I ran a model successfully. When I recall it using load_model_hdf5 I get a ValueError: Unknown config_item: L1L2. What is this error and how to I workaround it?

Here is the traceback:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Unknown config_item: L1L2 
16.
stop(structure(list(message = "ValueError: Unknown config_item: L1L2", 
    call = py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords), 
    cppstack = structure(list(file = "", line = -1L, stack = c("/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/reticulate/libs/reticulate.so(Rcpp::exception::exception(char const*, bool)+0x78) [0x7fed7c75fea8]", 
    "/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/reticulate/libs/reticulate.so(Rcpp::stop(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)+0x27) [0x7fed7c75ff17]",  ... 
15.
class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object at generic_utils.py#321
14.
deserialize_keras_object at generic_utils.py#362
13.
class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object at generic_utils.py#331
12.
deserialize_keras_object at generic_utils.py#362
11.
deserialize at serialization.py#109
10.
from_config at sequential.py#398
9.
deserialize_keras_object at generic_utils.py#373
8.
deserialize at serialization.py#109
7.
model_from_config at model_config.py#55
6.
load_model_from_hdf5 at hdf5_format.py#178
5.
load_model at save.py#184
4.
(structure(function (...) 
{
    dots <- py_resolve_dots(list(...))
    result <- py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) ... 
3.
do.call(keras$models$load_model, args) 
2.
load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile) 
1.
load_model_hdf5(paste0(dp, "model", i, ".unfrozen.h5"))
```

Comment: I resolved this by switching to Python and downloading TensorFlow 2.3. Tensorflow must have changed its dependency for R. Python works just fine using TensorFlow 2.3 for any of the tutorials, so my model in hd5 called just fine. I found lower versions <2.3 you need to install the nighty version of TensorFlow to get all the functionality of Tensorflow.